# Why is it necessary for Noether current to vanish at infinity "sufficiently quickly"?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, noethers-theorem

Watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cj-QpsZsDDY&t=415s) of a lecture by Tobias Osborne, I have difficulty understanding the significance of the modifier "sufficiently quickly" in his sentence:
$$S[\Phi_a] =  \int dx^4 \mathcal L = \int dx^4 (\mathcal{L}' +\partial_\mu F^\mu) $$
"As long as everything vanishes **sufficiently quickly** at infinity, you are free to add on total derivatives [$\partial_\mu F^\mu$] and you'll get the same action."

Interestingly, another lecturer (Dan Wohns) also makes a similar remark [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMicJ8GxkmA&start=2253):

"$\frac{dQ}{dt} = \cdots = - \int_{\partial \mathbb{R}^3}  \vec j. \vec {dS} =0, \quad $ if   $\vec j \rightarrow 0$ **quickly enough** as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$."

What do they mean by "quickly", or, "quickly enough"?

Answer (score 0):

What they mean is your expression has to go to zero sufficiently quickly for whatever sum or integral to converge. Take the second example with $j$, since the surface area of a sphere goes like $R^2$, $j$ must go to zero at infinity no slower than $1/R^2$ or else the integral doesnt converge for large $|x|$. For example if $j$ behaved like $1/R$ then the integral would diverge as $R$.

Comment: Is this correct? Sufficiently context (would seem to me) to mean that the boundary term vanishes, which in the first equation of the OP (in 4D) implies 1/R^alpha for alpha > 3 vanishing at infinity(?)